# Google Colaboratory disconnects after 10-15 minutes

Tags: deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train my Deep Learning model on Google colab where they offer a free K80 GPU. I learned that it can be used for 12 hours at a time and then you have to reconnect to it. But my connection is lost after 10-15 minutes and I cannot reconnect (it stays stuck on Initializing) . What's the issue here ?

Comment: This seems to be a bug and a lot of people are having the same issue. Restarting the kernel fixes it though.

Comment: I am using my college WiFi. They have a portal through which you need to login in order to use data could that be a problem ?

Comment: Also how do you restart the kernel on colab ?

Comment: If your connection drops, that could be a problem. For restarting kernel: Runtime > Restart runtime.

Comment: I also face the issue all the times.I have to stay active on colab tab to run it for more that 10-15 mins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proved to be a network issue in my university. My university has a login portal to access the internet. Bypassing it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to running a vision training model and it disconnects and stops sometime overnight. It runs hours and may be 12 hours. I also trained the model using the CPU and got the same results although without as many epochs completed. I have searched to see what the time limit is for the CPU without success. The training program uses tensorflow.saver to use checkpoints during training that allow for restarting training from a checkpoint when it is disrupted.

Comment: I am using a GPU. For how long did your instance stay connected on the GPU? Also, what environment are you using (browser , OS , python version etc , home Wifi / college wifi etc)