# Google Colab variable values lost after VM recycling

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using a Google Colab Jupyter notebook for algorithm training and have been struggling with an annoying problem. Since Colab is running in a VM environment, all my variables become undefined if my session is idle for a few hours. I come back from lunch and the training dataframe that takes a while to load becomes undefined and I have to `read_csv` again to load my dataframes.

Does anyone know how to rectify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the notebook is **idle for some time**, it might get recycled: "Virtual machines are recycled when idle for a while" (see [colaboratory faq](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html))
There is also an imposed hard limit for a virtual machine to run (up to about 12 hours !?).

What could also happen is that your notebook gets **disconnected from the internet** / google colab. This could be an issue with your network. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49611472/google-colaboratory-disconnects-after-10-15-minutes) or [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/88ywbo/google_colaboratory_gets_disconnected_after_1015/)

There are no ways to "rectify" this, but if you have processed some data you could add a step to save it to google drive before entering the *idle* state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When you say 'add a step to save it to google drive', do you mean using something like 'pickle' to dump the variables to google drive? Or is there a cleverer way to save variables to google drive?

Comment: Yes, I meant save them using pickle and then uploading them to google drive using one of these methods https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

- You can use **local runtime** with Google Colab. Doing so, the Colab notebook will use your own machine's resources, and you won't have any limits. More on this: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html
- There are various ways to **save your data** in the process:

  - you can save on the Notebook's VM filesystem, e. g. `pd.to_csv("my_data.csv")`
  - you can `import sqlite3` which is the Python implementation of the popular SQLite database. Difference between SQLite and other SQL databases is that the DBMS runs inside your application, and data is saved to the file system of that application. Info: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html
  - you can save to your google drive, download to your local file system through your browser, upload to GCP... more info here: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=eikfzi8ZT_rW